# Change active class after 5 seconds (and prevent change if user is hovering over item)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, settimeout

I'm building out a simple tabbed section where each tab will become active every 5 seconds.

Initially `trigger 1` in my demo will be active, then after 5 seconds, the aim is to make `trigger 2` active (at this point, `trigger 1` will not be active) and so on.

In addition to this, if, for example, `trigger 1` is active, but a user wants to access `trigger 5`, I want the timeout function to pause when it's hovering over a trigger item.

I'm having difficulties with getting the next trigger to show as active and to pause the timeout when the mouse is over `.trigger-single`

Demo:

```js
$(function() {

    // add active class to first item
  $(".triggers .trigger-single:first-child").addClass("activeTrigger");
  
  // users can also click to the trigger they want, when doing so
  $('.triggers .trigger-single').click(function() {
    $(".triggers .trigger-single").removeClass("activeTrigger");
    $(this).addClass("activeTrigger");
  });
  
  // trying to get the next trigger to be active after 5 seconds
  window.setTimeout(function(){
    $(".triggers .trigger-single").closest(".trigger-single").removeClass("activeTrigger").addClass("activeTrigger");
  },5000);

});
```

```css
.triggers{
  display: flex;
}

.trigger-single{
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.activeTrigger{
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="triggers">
  <div class="trigger-single">Trigger 1</div>
  <div class="trigger-single">Trigger 2</div>
  <div class="trigger-single">Trigger 3</div>
  <div class="trigger-single">Trigger 4</div>
  <div class="trigger-single">Trigger 5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sfwo6gxn/

Comment: @natel - This fiddle doesn't do what I want?

Comment: Do you see how .hover is used in that example?  It's a hint.

Comment: As for the timeout and counter part, here's some code that would help with that. https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/pvk6p/  You might be able to answer your own question now.